# Can't pass custom UINavigationBar / UIToolbar to UINavigationController because they don't conform to AnyClass

Tags: ios

So...`class MyToolbar: UIToolbar` does not conform to `AnyClass` nor does my `class MyNavigationBar: UINavigationBar`.

I'm totally at a loss. Dosen't every class conform to `AnyClass?

I've tried to do this by having them inherit from NSObject or even trying from Objective C but there I get a warning `Incompatible pointer types sending 'MyNewNavBar *' to parameter of type 'Class _Nullable'` and when I compile and run I get an even crazier error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyNewNavBar isSubclassOfClass:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd411700e10'`

Isn't this method `isSubclassOfClass:aClass` supposed to be on everything? Or at least on NSObject? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418669-issubclassofclass

[image: Crazy Inheritance]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it :) You need to refer to the class as a Type :)

```
super.init(navigationBarClass: MyNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: MyToolbar.self)
```